# Javascript issue: pulling up checked items and displaying them (like a shopping cart)

Tags: javascript

Okay so here is my HTML

```
 <!--Enveloppe principale - wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
<h1> Magasin de musique </h1>
<form id="musictems" name="musicitems">

 <!--Enveloppe magasin - storewrapper -->
<div id="storewrapper">
 <div class="collections">
    <h2>Collections de musique </h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th class="lrpadding">Prix</th>
            <th>Quantit&eacute;</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="135.50" name="collectioncheckboxes"/></td>
            <td>Collection 1</td>
            <td class="lrpadding">$135.50</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c1qty" size="4"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="129.99" name="collectioncheckboxes"/></td>
            <td>Collection 2</td>
            <td class="lrpadding">$129.99</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c2qty" size="4"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="145.99" name="collectioncheckboxes"/></td>
            <td>Collection 3</td>
            <td class="lrpadding">$145.99</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c3qty" size="4"></td>
     </tr>
   </table>              
 </div>
```

Basically just check boxes for items and a quantity box next to it. The purpose is to display all the items checked, multiply their value by the quantity, and produce the total. 
I asked this question earlier and someone gave me some helpful tips but everytime I try to run my code/function, nothing happens!

Here's my javascript:

```
 function calculerAfficherDetailsAchats ()
     {

      var c1 = document.getElementsByName("collectioncheckboxes");

      var totalcost = 0;


      var header = "<table><tr><th class='pname'>Product Name</th>" +
            "<th class='price'>Prix</th></tr>";

      var body ="";


     if(collectioncheckboxes[0].checked)
     {
         var price = parseFloat(collectioncheckboxes[0].value);
         totalcost = totalcost + price
         var fdesc = "item1";
         body = body + "<tr><td class='fname'>"+fdesc +"</td>"+ "<td class='price'>"+price+"</td></tr>";
     }

     if(collectioncheckboxes[1].checked)
     {
         var price = parseFloat(collectioncheckboxes[1].value);
         totalcost = totalcost + price;
         var fdesc = "item2";
         body = body + "<tr><td class='fname'>"+fdesc +"</td>"+ "<td class='price'>"+price+"</td></tr>";
     }

     if(collectioncheckboxes[2].checked)
     {
         var price = parseFloat(collectioncheckboxes[2].value);
         totalcost = totalcost + price;
         var fdesc = "item3";
         body = body + "<tr><td class='fname'>"+fdesc +"</td>"+ "<td class='price'>"+price+"</td></tr>";
     }

     var footer = "<tr><td> Cout total </td><td class='totalcost'>" + totalcost +"$</td></tr></table>";
     costinfo = header + body + footer;

      totalcost.innerHTML = costinfo;
      totalcost.style.display = "block";
   }
```

So ya, I just can't figure out why nothing at all is happening to begin with! If I can get something to display from this, then I can focus on multiplying by the quantity... Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: try changing `collectioncheckboxes[0]` for `c1[0]` since that's the name of the variable you gave it

Comment: 'cause you defined a function, a-and... never call it?

Comment: Please change your question title to something more useful. I mean, *pleeeeease* change it.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that, I did change it to c1[0] and etc, but still no luck.

Comment: And I do call it by pressing a button. The button calls that function, and it's code is tested and working. It's the actual function that doesn't run properly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a start. At least it doesn't blow up:

http://jsfiddle.net/57b6z5hv/

You need to learn to use a debugger. There were several JavaScript errors in your code.

One of the weird things you had was this:

```
var totalcost = 0;
//(SNIP)
 totalcost = totalcost + price;
//(SNIP)
totalcost.innerHTML = costinfo;
totalcost.style.display = "block";
```

So, you were storing totalcost in a number variable and then turing around and treating it like a DOM element. I'm *assuming* you meant to have a div called totalcost or something, and that you wanted something like:

```
document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML = costinfo;
```

Of course, you also need a totalCost div. As I said, there are a LOT of things wrong with this code.

Comment: Ah thanks so much. For the tips and the code; your assumption was on point! I did have a bunch of things wrong but ya I managed to get it working :). Really appreciate your help.